# Abbreviation in a business letter

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

[image: Handwritten letter]
[image: Handwritten letter]
In transcribing a business letter written in 1776, I keep finding an apparent abbreviation, 'qsd' with a line over the s, e.g "this to be qsd my brother." Can anyone tell me what this means?
The letters are hand-written by William Phelps in London to James Morrissey in Madeira and concern the shipping of wine and other commodities between England and Madeira. William, his brother Joseph and James M were in partnership. 
I have attached further screen shots.
[image: Handwritten letter]

Below are transcriptions of three passages which include the elusive qsd.
"The first ten pps was for Mr Thomas Neale to be qsd my Brother, & the nature of his transaction with us, was you see invested in Wheat,…"

"...& write them to the purport of the letter. I shall write by them, where you may amend as you think proper. One for Mr Hemsted you will ship & one for Capn Miller's owner, this latter to be qsd my Brother & included for account & risque as per advice, having his order by me. Mr Hemsted you will write inclosing him bill of lading for it."

"The five pps of Wine shipt by Wylie have qsd over to Mr Morris, wch made a Ballance for the Furniture had by my Brother, for here & Madeira, so we have no Wines coming our account, but those you will have shipt by Forster & Laurie & I hope shall gett rid of all those on hand long ere those arrive."

I feel that it must be a verb, with a meaning such as "charged to" or "consigned to".

Comment: Can you give more context? My guess is that "my brother" is a familiar way to refer to the recipient of the letter, and "to be qsd" somehow suggests how the information in the letter should be handled -- perhaps something similar to "on the QT", meaning to keep the information to yourself.

Comment: "Quod sine die" (without day), perhaps? The letter s with a macron is short for *sine*. Since I have no Latin, it's the best that I can do.

Comment: ... or maybe "quod sine dictum" (that without mentioning)?

Comment: I didn't find it in *Latin for the Illiterati*, a book of common words and expressions, common phrases and familiar sayings, and abbreviations. *Sine die (s.d.)* means indefinitely. *s bar s bar (semis)* means one half. *s bar* doesn't appear, but other searches indicate that it means *without*, as indicated by @Mick. See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_medical_abbreviations:_S>.

Comment: @TomCotton on Latin.SE tells me that is means *quod sine dicto* (don't wait to be told).

Comment: I'd like to see more context, but this looks to me like a nonce-abbreviation for "questioned".

Comment: @StoneyB It could just be. My searching has drawn a blank.

Comment: In handwriting and, to a somewhat lesser extent, printed material from 1776, the long s would have been much more likely. I suspect what you're seeing is a familiar abbreviation for 'quod' (= 'quoth'), commonly abbreviated in epistles as qd (often without the point in 1600-1700s). Knowing whether the letter is handwritten or printed, other context, ideally a screenshot or snapshot would help us assist you.

Comment: @Hugh in Latin.SE has provided a very useful comment. Rather than copy and paste it, here is a link to my question: [Possible abbreviation for a Latin phrase](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/possible-abbreviation-for-a-latin-phrase).

Comment: @All I'm wondering if we should get this question transferred to Latin.SE? They seem to be doing all the work and it looks more and more like it's in their bailiwick.

Comment: A non-Latin issue is the meaning of "my brother" in this context, and that would inform the selection between the apparently vast set of Latin answers.  If "my brother" is used several times in the letter it would be valuable to know what those contexts are.

Comment: If it's English, probably 'questioned.' (StonyB=) If it's Latin, lower case, with no stops, likely to be *quaesendum* / *quaesenda* 'to be checked out.' If it is Upper case with stops I suggested (Latin SE) *Quod (quae) super dixi* 'Which thing(s) I said before.'

Comment: @Penelope Our friends in Latin.SE have asked if we can provide with a scan of the letter that you are transcribing, even if it is only partial? If the abbreviation is of a Latin word or phrase, seeing the actual script can provide more information than a typewritten transcription.

Comment: "With a line over the s" ... Did you mean s̄ ? It makes me believe that you have a handwritten letter. But more context is needed or a miracle.

Comment: Shot in the dark ... This may not be relevant, but users may find it of interest. "Questions for short debate (QSDs) are the principal means by which backbenchers secure 1-1½ hour debates in the Chamber or Grand Committee [in the U.K. House of Lords]." See http://www.lordswhips.org.uk/qsds. This term could date back at least to the American Revolution. On the off chance this is correct, the the OPs sentence would read, "this to be question for short debate my brother".

Comment: Many thanks for these replies, though none seems exactly right. I have added more information to my question.

Comment: The image certainly helps show what the characters look like. More context would help as well though. Are you able to edit the entire paragraph into the question text? (Currently the question text doesn't match the image, which may not matter; or it may confuse things further.)

Comment: Is that a short s? The long one ( ſ ) should have been used there, so I'm wondering if it's significant. (Of if the problem is I can't read 18th century cursive.)

Comment: So grateful for your continued interest! More screenshots added.

Comment: @Laurel The handwriting is beautiful but I am unable to read a word of it. It is indeed cursive - I cursed it something chronic!

Comment: @PeterPoint. Having transcribed hundreds of old letters (mostly C19th) I find I can read most of the writing. Just this word baffles me!

Comment: @Laurel I've added some transcriptions - sympathise with your curses; often resort to them myself.

Comment: @Mick So grateful for your help. I hope the added scans and transcriptions add some light.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia

### £sd

> **[£sd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A3sd)** (occasionally written Lsd) is the popular name for the pre-decimal currencies once common throughout Europe, especially in the British Isles and hence in several countries of the British Empire and subsequently the Commonwealth. The abbreviation originates from the Latin currency denominations *librae*, solidi, and *denarii*. In the United Kingdom, which was one of the last to abandon the system, these were referred to as pounds, shillings, and pence (pence being the plural of penny). When spoken it was pronounced "ell-ess-dee", or more commonly "pounds, shillings and pence".

further in the same article

> **[Colloquial terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%A3sd#Colloquial_terms)**
>   ...
>   A sixpenny bit was a "tanner" (in Australia a "zack"), one shilling was a "bob", and a pound a "nicker" or a "quid".* The term "quid" is said to originate from the Latin phrase *quid pro quo*.

It appears the correspondent is discussing financial transactions in qsd or quid, shillings and pence (as against the local currency of Madeira).

Comment: /as you say, it seems to mean "consign to", perhaps as a payment in kind.'... as @ToyK seems to suggest below.  http://english.stackexchange.com/a/369705/52721

Answer (score 0):

There's another page on the subject with some good information and suggestions, and a source stating that the abbreviation was not in widespread official use in that time.

https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/is-qsd-an-abbreviation-for-a-latin-phrase/2042#2042?newreg=0327f55252a34fabbc849b95383f9d08

Perhaps the writer was fond of the word "Questioned"... This is to be questioned, my brother. You have much less chance of finding good interpretations if you only post one example in context, as the context is of major importance in all it's instances.

Quis Sicut Deus.
"As I said before," quae supra dixi.

Answer (score 0):

You provided the wrong transcription for the first scan. Here is my attempt:

> ...either lost, or gone to America. Acknowledg'd y' receipt of your
>   two letters the 9 and 20 June, via Port Lorient, wherin you
>   acknowledgd the punctuall pay of the Shopkeepers, & the lessening (?)
>   you had made of Dom: Mander's account, wch was glad to hear. Capn
>   Miller was certainly qs'd us, we had put on Board the undermentioned
>   Articles.

(I can't work out what that y' might mean.)

I suspect that the verb is "qs", pronounced "cue ess", and those macrons are apostrophes. (Or perhaps the macron spans both the q and the s, to indicate an abbreviation?) It is presumably short for something, but I can't work out what; from the context, as you say, it seems to mean "consign to", perhaps as a payment in kind.

Answer (score -4):

Quis ut Deus, qsd, latin probably. See http://latin.dechile.net/?Abreviaturas=61

Comment: "Who is like God?" How does *that* fit the context?

Comment: Afraid that doesn't fit the context at all. It is clearly a verb and must mean something like 'charged to' or 'consigned to'.

Comment: The tradition was until the last 100 years, for business men to say, when promising to deliver a service or good, to say, "If the Lord will", "If the Lord allow", or the shorter, "Lord willing" a well-known example of this is found in the Bible in James 4:15. In the King James version: "For that ye ought to say, If the Lord will, we shall live, and do this, or that." QSD = "Who to God" is a similar phrase. Now, being businessmen, and wanting to save money on ink, will abbreviate common phrases.